# Passing the id of an HTML <li> tag to a VBScript subroutine when clicked on

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

I have loads of VBScripts that I plan to give a GUI front end (using an HTA). At the top of the HTA's window I have a drop down menu bar created as follows (haven't included CSS code as I don't think that it adds any relevent information).

I have been trying for sometime but have been unable to work out how I can pass the value of the id of the clicked li to the MenuClicked subroutine.

My previous experience with HTML was using it to create static documents so I might have got this all wrong. If that is the case then please let me know.

```
<script type="text/VBScript">
  Sub MenuClicked()
    Select Case WhatDoIPutHere
      Case "#Option1A" : Sub_Option1A
      Case "#Option1B" : Sub_Option1B
      Case "#Option2A" : Sub_Option2A
      Case "#Option2B" : Sub_Option2B
      Case "#Option3"  : Sub_Option3
    End Select
  End Sub
</script>

<div>
  <ul id="nav" class="drop" onClick="MenuClicked()">
    <li><a>Option1A</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="#Option1A"><a>Option 1A</a></li>
        <li id="#Option1B"><a>Option 1B</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Option 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="#Option2A"><a>Option 2A</a></li>
        <li id="#Option2B"><a>Option 2B</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="#Option3"><a>Option 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since HTAs are run by an Internet Explorer engine, you should use the [`srcElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property

```
<script type="text/VBScript">
  Sub MenuClicked()
    Dim target

    ' .parentNode because the <a> element is really what's being clicked,
    ' but we want the ID of the <li> element
    Set target = window.event.srcElement.parentNode

    Select Case target.id
      Case "#Option1A" : Sub_Option1A
      Case "#Option1B" : Sub_Option1B
      Case "#Option2A" : Sub_Option2A
      Case "#Option2B" : Sub_Option2B
      Case "#Option3"  : Sub_Option3
    End Select
  End Sub
</script>

<div>
  <ul id="nav" class="drop" onClick="MenuClicked()">
    <li><a>Option1A</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="#Option1A"><a>Option 1A</a></li>
        <li id="#Option1B"><a>Option 1B</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Option 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="#Option2A"><a>Option 2A</a></li>
        <li id="#Option2B"><a>Option 2B</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="#Option3"><a>Option 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, that is probably better idea because you don't need to repeat `onclick` everywhere.

Comment: Had another look at this and realized that you can add an onMouseOver to call a modified version of the onClick routine. My HTA now displays text in a 'status line' that gives additional information on the menu option being pointed to. Thanks Cheran.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
<script type="text/VBScript">
  Sub MenuClicked(obj)
    Select Case obj.id
      Case "#Option1A" : Sub_Option1A
      Case "#Option1B" : Sub_Option1B
      Case "#Option2A" : Sub_Option2A
      Case "#Option2B" : Sub_Option2B
      Case "#Option3"  : Sub_Option3
    End Select
  End Sub
</script>

<div>
  <ul id="nav" class="drop">
    <li><a>Option1A</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="#Option1A" onClick="MenuClicked Me"><a>Option 1A</a></li>
        <li id="#Option1B" onClick="MenuClicked Me"><a>Option 1B</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Option 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="#Option2A" onClick="MenuClicked Me"><a>Option 2A</a></li>
        <li id="#Option2B" onClick="MenuClicked Me"><a>Option 2B</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="#Option3" onClick="MenuClicked Me"><a>Option 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```